# The repository 'ROS package cosmic Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I'm new with ROS, i'm trying install it in Ubuntu 18.10.

I used the [install ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) documentation for all [ROS versions](http://www.ros.org/install/)

I run:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

where I get `cosmic` as output in `lsb_release -sc` command

I add the repo-key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

and when i will update the repository I get an error:

```
sudo apt-get update
[...]
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

How can I install the ROS in a cosmic ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

ROS Melodic is Not available on Ubuntu Cosmetic(18.10) package manager. I think You can compile it from source here in [ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source)